# Unable to reply to review in arabic ,using AGC Connect API

Tags: rest, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, agconnect-functions

Got an error { ret: { rtnCode: 50010003, rtnDesc: 'param error' } }

Tried with lang as ar_AE as well as ara_AE.

Answer (score 1):

This error code 50010003 will come when you will provide any incorrect parameters . Please identify and check it.

For details please refer to: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-References/agcapi-comment-returncode-0000001116028252

[image]

POST https://connect-api.cloud.huawei.com/api/reviews/v1/manage/dev/reviews
Content-Type: application/json
client_id: ***
Authorization: Bearer ***
requestId: xxxxxxx

{
"lang": "ara_AE",
"appId": "300148173",
"reviewId": "9f43c56228854d66a65921938199c0ce",
"devReplyContent": "Reply content......",
"countryCode": "AE"
}

[image]

For Details , please refer to: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-References/agcapi-com-reviewreply-0000001162548117